# CABasicAnimation performance issues in CMMotionManager Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, cabasicanimation

I have a CMMotionManager setup with the deviceMotionUpdateInterval set at 100 HZ like so:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/100.0;
```

I am using a block like so to get yaw values from the gyroscope

```
    [motionManger startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) { //get yaw values}];
```

I also have a CABasicAnimation that is being animated in the same block. I have the duration of each animation set at 0.01 seconds. The animation is a circular progress bar representing how many degrees the device has been rotated. This works perfectly on an iPhone 5. However on older devices like the iPhone 4 and 4S, there is significant delay between the progress bar being filled and the actual degree value the device has rotated. Basically, if the phone has rotated 180 degrees quickly, the progress bar will fill much slower to get to the 180 degree point. In the same scenario on an iPhone 5, the progress bar will be at the 180 degree point instantaneously.

My question is, what can I do to improve the performance so that animations are smooth and instantaneously accurate like the iPhone 5?

Comment: Use Instruments to figure out what's happening. You probably are contending for the CPU. iPhone 5 has a dual core CPU so it is truly multithreaded. iPhone 4, I'm guessing, the animation can't get going because we keep getting hammered by calls to your yaw update block.

Comment: Can you advise on what to monitor exactly in Instruments? CPU time? Animation frame rate?

Comment: Yeah, I would think you could do a Time Profiler and see what's slowing down the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659352/cmmotionmanager-vs-uiaccelerometer-efficiency/17716398#17716398).

In short, the block method has significant overhead, and you need to manually poll the CMMotionManager at your chosen interval.  It is detailed under "Periodic Sampling of Motion Data" in the CMMotionManager Class Reference.