# CMMotionManager vs UIAccelerometer efficiency

Tags: ios, performance, math, uiaccelerometer, cmmotionmanager

I've been working on an [AR framework](https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality) for a while now and am trying to [update from UIAccelerometer (deprecated) to CMMotionManager](https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality/issues/23) but am running into some efficiency problems?

Basically it seems like CMMotionManager is MUCH larger and slower than UIAccelerometer is. Has anyone experienced performance issues with CMMotionManager before?

---

As you can see [here](https://github.com/promet/PRAugmentedReality/blob/master/Classes/Location/LocationWork.m), I had this:

```
accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accelerometer.updateInterval = 0.01;
[accelerometer setDelegate:self];
```

and

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    rollingZ  = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ  * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    rollingX = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

    if (rollingZ > 0.0)      currentInclination = inc_avg(atan(rollingX / rollingZ) + M_PI / 2.0);
    else if (rollingZ < 0.0) currentInclination = inc_avg(atan(rollingX / rollingZ) - M_PI / 2.0);
    else if (rollingX < 0)   currentInclination = inc_avg(M_PI/2.0);
    else if (rollingX >= 0)  currentInclination = inc_avg(3 * M_PI/2.0);
}
```

and all works great even on "older" devices like the iPhone 4 (not really old but yea...).

But when trying the exact same code but with CMMotionManager:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
```

with

```
[motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:0.01];
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                    withHandler: ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error){

                                        rollingZ = (accelerometerData.acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ  * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
                                        rollingX = (accelerometerData.acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

                                        if (rollingZ > 0.0)      currentInclination = inc_avg(atan(rollingX / rollingZ) + M_PI / 2.0);
                                        else if (rollingZ < 0.0) currentInclination = inc_avg(atan(rollingX / rollingZ) - M_PI / 2.0);
                                        else if (rollingX < 0)   currentInclination = inc_avg(M_PI/2.0);
                                        else if (rollingX >= 0)  currentInclination = inc_avg(3 * M_PI/2.0);
                                    }];
```

The math seems to slow the crap out of it..! I say this because when I remove all the math part it works great.

An iPhone 5 will work alright but an iPhone 4S will show signs of lag and the iPhone 4 will just freeze...

(I can give you more details if you want but its relatively complicated to explain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just having this same problem, and wouldn't you know it, the solution was in the documentation ;)

The problem is with the block format.  All of the tutorials seem to favor that method, but Apple recommends periodic polling of the `CMMotionManager` as a more performance oriented approach.  The block format adds overhead.

From the `CMMotionManager` Class Reference:

> To handle motion data by periodic sampling, the app calls a “start”
>   method taking no arguments and periodically accesses the motion data
>   held by a property for a given type of motion data. This approach is
>   the recommended approach for apps such as games. Handling
>   accelerometer data in a block introduces additional overhead, and most
>   game apps are interested only the latest sample of motion data when
>   they render a frame.

So what you want to do, from the docs again:

> Call startAccelerometerUpdates to begin updates and periodically
>   access CMAccelerometerData objects by reading the accelerometerData
>   property.

Something along these lines

```
CMMotionManager *mManager = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];

[mManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

Then, in some sort of periodically updating method of your choosing:

```
CMMotionManager *mManager = [(SEPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedManager];

CMAccelerometerData *aData = mManager.accelerometerData;
```

This solution appears to work as well as `UIAccelerometer` on an iPhone 4 from the limited testing I've done.

Answer (score 4):

I use **CADisplayLink**.

First, setup **CMMotionManager** instance.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init];

    if(self.motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable)
    {
        [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
    }


    [self setupDisplayLink];
}
```

Secondly setup **displaylink** instance like this:

```
-(void)setupDisplayLink
{
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];
    displayLink.frameInterval = 10;// how many frames to skip before next update
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Display link is an object that is connected to your device screen, and which can run specified selector with specified frame rate; More on them [here](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Thirdly you should implement update: method you specified as display link selector.

```
-(void)update:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    // handle new accelerometer data here
    CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = self.motionManager.deviceMotion;
    NSLog(@"Acceleration: %@", deviceMotion.accelerometerData.acceleration);
}
```

Comment: Last line: Should be: `deviceMotion.accelerometerData.gravity`.

Comment: I think DisplayLink is the better solution but you have to invalid displaylink to avoid retain cycle because displaylink retains runloop.